# Upcase package name problems

Tags: android, gradle

I need update old android app in play market. But my predecessors uploaded old app with "DNT.Rexten" as package name. My new app build with android studio(gradle) and I can't upload apk on device with "DNT.Rexten" cause "Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]" 
I find out that problem comes from first symbol upcase.
Console build doesn't help, I think problem in gradle.
What can I do?

P.S. Package name is not real, but problem is.

Comment: What's in your manifest and your gradle build files? Also, what shows up in logcat when the install fails?

Answer (score 0):

> Package names are written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the
>   names of classes or interfaces.

Change your package name to `dnt.rexten` to correct this issue.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Comment: thanks, but I can't. I need find way capitalize first symbol in package name or I will not be capable update old application in play market. To deploy update I need same key and same package name.
Old application is old (Xamarin based) and previous developers have found way capitalize package name (I know it wrong)